# InAppSettingsKit empty on phone, OK on Simulator

Tags: inappsettingskit

I use IASK in a just plain way. It works beautifully on the simulator.

[image: IASK on Simulator]

But for reasons that I cannot grasp it doesn't on my device

[image: IASK on iPhone]

What I checked so far : 
- code to initialize IASK is fine, 100% demo
- Got rid of Root~iphone.inApp.plist
- Got rid of en.lproj and fr.lproj in the settings bundle.
- erased the app from the iPhone and cleaned source
- checked the settings.app (OK)

I'm at a loss…

Here's the code :

```
- (IASKAppSettingsViewController*)appSettingsViewController {
if (!appSettingsViewController) {
    appSettingsViewController = [[IASKAppSettingsViewController alloc] init];
    appSettingsViewController.delegate = self;
    }
return appSettingsViewController;
}

aNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:self.appSettingsViewController];
self.appSettingsViewController.showDoneButton = YES;
[self presentViewController:aNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Which is actually straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was voodoo. After much tinkering, it worked. But putting back all resources as they were, it still worked.

To help anybody who has similar issues, here's what I did :

- replaced my settings.bundle with a brand new one, pristine.
- checked in IASK that it found the bundle
- checked that the table view cells were indeed filled

and everything was OK. But the view was still empty. And then, I just put another breakpoint, restarted the app, and it worked…

I prefer when my code is wrong. Here I don't know what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that settings are in Root.inapp.plist rather than Root.inApp.plist. Most macOS users have a case insensitive filesystem, whereas iOS behaves as if it is case sensitive. That's why it works in the simulator but not on the device.